# WACOM Tablet will only work if plugged in USB at boot time

Tags: 14.04, usb, wacom

This is on UBUNTU 14.04 LTS

If I plug my WACOM (Intuos4 PTK-440) into USB AFTER I boot or if I unplug and replug, without booting, the tablet does not respond.

YET I do get :

```
$ lsusb
Bus 003 Device 016: ID 056a:00b8 Wacom Co., Ltd Intuos4 4x6

dmesg
[234491.960080] usb 3-1: new full-speed USB device number 16 using xhci_hcd
[234492.088883] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=056a, idProduct=00b8
[234492.088889] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[234492.088892] usb 3-1: Product: PTK-440
[234492.088895] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: Tablet
[234492.089936] input: Wacom Intuos4 4x6 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/input/input28
```

In `/dev/input/by-id`:

```
usb-Tablet_PTK-440-event-mouse
usb-Tablet_PTK-440-mouse
```

Furthermore Gimp "sees" it (eraser, pad, stylus and cursor)

If I reboot with the tablet plugged into USB it all works.

How do I proceed?

Comment: How logs from boot and replug differ? How the list of X.org input devices differ? What is the difference if you log X input events in both cases?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

here is a quick script that allows you to plug and unplug a wacom tablet from your system without restarting the computer

```
#!/bin/bash
WACOM=`lsusb | grep -i wacom | awk '{print $7}'`
 if [[ $WACOM = "Wacom" ]]; then
    echo" you will have to enter your password " \n
    sudo modprobe -r wacom;
    sudo modprobe -a wacom;
 else 
    echo " no wacom was found check usb" \n
  fi 
  exit
```